# ExecuteExcel4Macro , Is there any way to reference worksheet by index instead of its name in Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-4.0

I would like to reference worksheet by index method for the worksheet without open the workbook. However, I don't know how to do it for this. Many example from online is using "Sheet1", which is not my case. For my case, each workbook has its worksheetname, They are all named differently.

```
Sub excelfor_macro()
Dim p As String, f As String
Dim s As String, a As String
Dim my_array(1 To 8) As String
Dim r As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
p = "C:\Users\puntek\Desktop\"
f = "490XXZMAV31002S84D6A_002S84D68.xlsx"
s = SHEETNAME(1).Name  **'This is where, i want to reference by index, not worksheet name**

For r = 1 To 8
    a = Cells(r + 8, 3).Address 'start from row 9 the info
    my_array(r) = GetValue(p, f, s, a)
Next r
End Sub

Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref) 'This is getvalue function, the worksheetname will pass to sheet
Dim arg As String
If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
    GetValue = "File Not Found"
    Exit Function
End If
arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
Range(ref).Address(, , xlR1C1)
GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

Comment: `Worksheets(1)` will refer to it by index, just hope the order does not change.

Comment: Hi @braX , do u mean replacing 
`arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & Worksheets(1) & "'!" & _
Range(ref).Address(, , xlR1C1)`
But it doesn't work this way.

Comment: No, `s = Worksheets(1).Name` - assuming the rest works - I guess you would have to open the workbook first, set that first, so you can access the collection. I dont think it's going to work the way you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Open the workbook to get the name:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
p = "C:\Users\puntek\Desktop\"
f = "490XXZMAV31002S84D6A_002S84D68.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(p & f) ' or Set wb = Workbooks.Add(p & f)
s = wb.Worksheets(1).Name
' optionally close the workbook
wb.Close
```

Comment: Hi brax, Thanks for the prompt answer. May i know is there any way to get worksheetname without open the workbook ? This is because, i am working with hundreds of workbook, open workbook will significantly run slower.

Comment: Hmm according to this, the way you are trying to do it might work - havent tried it tho... https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4227-excel-reference-sheet-by-number.html#:~:text=Notes%3A,then%20press%20the%20Enter%20key. When you debug it, what values is it returning?

Comment: thanks for the link, but the link method requires to openworkbook in order to get the worksheetname.
When debugging i get ERROR 2023

Comment: Yeah, as I said, I don't think there's a way to do it the way you want to. Maybe someone else will have some ideas.